# Join para registros desiguais no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho dois data frames chamados empregados e funcionários.

```
nome.empregado <- c('Renato', 'Miguel', 'Paulo', 'Patrícia', 'Inês', 'Saulo', 
  'Diego', 'Maria', 'Jose', 'Julia', 'Tiago')
idade <- c(30, 31, 29, 30, 25, 30, 30, 35, 24, 31, 29)
empregados <- data.frame(nome.empregado, idade)

nome.empregado <- c('Renato', 'Miguel', 'Paulo', 'Patrícia', 'Inês', 'Saulo', 
  'Diego', 'Maria', 'Jose', 'Julia', 'Tiago','Carla')
idade <- c(30, 31, 29, 30, 25, 30, 30, 35, 24, 31, 29, 50)
funcionarios <- data.frame(nome.empregado, idade)
```

Necessito fazer um join para selecionar apenas os registros desiguais. No meu exemplo acima, tenho que encontrar apenas a linha com o nome Carla. Tentei usando a função `merge` e não consegui.  Gostaria da ajuda para este problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função `anti_join` do pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(funcionarios, empregados)
```

Ela vai dar uma mensagem de warning, mas não se preocupe. É irrelevante neste caso.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você não necessita do *Merge*, apenas utilizar um *RIGTH JOIN* para os registros que aparecem apenas na tabela da direita, ou seja, o registro da tabela da esquerda será nula.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA TA
RIGHT JOIN TableB TB
    ON TA.NomeEmpregado = TB.NomeEmpregado
WHERE TA.NomeEmpregado IS NULL
```